# Can't see the Difference between Spring and Eclipse-Link framework

Tags: spring, eclipselink

I am bit confused about the difference between Spring and Eclipse-Link framework.
Could you help me with some explication.
Thank you.

Comment: EclipseLink is a JPA implementation. Spring is a multi-purpose application framework based on a dependency injection engine, which (among other things) allow easy integration of JPA, of which EclipseLink is an implementation. So your question is basically similar to "I can't understand the difference between a hard-disk and a computer.

Comment: Ok. Thank you :)